# Quartz.Net cron expression for immediate fire followed by 1 minute gap

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need help on a proper cron expression that will fire the job immediately after it's launched, then reoccurring every minutes thereafter. So far I have

```
0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *?
```

But that only fires at the minute mark (i.e. 3:31:00, 3:32:00). So if I launch the job at 3:45:54, I want it to execute right away, then the next fire would be at 3:46:54.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with a cron expression but you can use `SimpleScheduleBuilder` using `WithSimpleSchedule`:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "gruppone")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
    .Build();
```

and this would be the end result:

```
27/09/2015 12:28:28 +01:00
27/09/2015 12:29:28 +01:00
27/09/2015 12:30:28 +01:00
27/09/2015 12:31:28 +01:00
27/09/2015 12:32:28 +01:00
27/09/2015 12:33:28 +01:00
```